# How do I get the unique values in each Cells with multiple values and sum up the total value occurrence in each column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the unique values in each Cells with multiple values and sum up the total value occurrence in each column.

```
Example:
Name  A1        B1     C1
John  1,2,2,2   1,1,1  2,2,2
Cat   2,3,3,3   1,2,3  1,3,3
Dog   3,4       2,3    1
```

The answer I will get:

```
       A1             B1             C1            Sum
Values - Count Values - Count Values - Count Values - Count    
     1 - 1          1 - 2          1 - 1          1 - 4
     2 - 2          2 - 2          2 - 2          2 - 6
     3 - 2          3 - 2          3 - 1          3 - 6
     4 - 1                                        4 - 1
```

Comment: In your sample dataframe are those strings or lists?  Also, could you put in this question the code to generate your input sample dataframe?

Comment: hard to follow your logic here, why B1 3 count have 3 times ?

Comment: They are in strings, this dataframe is generated from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You may can do

```
s=df.loc[:,'A1':].applymap(lambda x : list(set(x.split(',')))).sum()
df=pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)
yourdf=df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(0)
yourdf['sum']=yourdf.sum(1)
yourdf
Out[378]: 
    A1   B1   C1  sum
1  1.0  2.0  2.0  5.0
2  2.0  2.0  1.0  5.0
3  2.0  2.0  1.0  5.0
4  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```